# How to dispatch events in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

How can I dispatch events in Haxe using the JavaScript target? Is there a recommended library?

Any idea? I tried to search the Haxe website, but I couldn't find a native approach to solve the problem.

Comment: Is this search query helpful? https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=haxe+dispatchevent

Comment: no, too old results, and framework based solutions, I need a built in solution in haxe, but it seems there is no implementation for js

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on what platform you are targeting.

If it's the js target, then you will use the normal js api in Haxe.

Take a look here to see how to use js in Haxe :
http://philippe.elsass.me/2014/11/vanilla-haxe-js/

and you can check that out the js event api here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events